# How many squares can a limp queen move to?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization, checkerboard, packing

Consider a large chessboard. A *limp rook* is a chess piece that moves one step orthogonally, but it turns $90$ degrees after every move. The limp rook makes some moves, not crossing over its own path, and returning to the starting cell. It is known (see [IMO Shortlist 2009 C6](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h355787p1932931)) that on an $n$ by $n$ grid, if $n$ is $3$ modulo $4$, the maximum number of steps the limp rook can take is $n^2-2n-3$.

A *limp queen* moves one step either orthogonally or diagonally, but it turns $45$ degrees instead (so changing its movement direction). How many cells can it visit in a cyclic path (not revisiting a square until the end) on an $n$ by $n$ grid if $n$ is $8$? $10$? How many for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: To clarify: must the queen be a knight’s move away from its starting position after its second move?

Comment: Yes, since it turns 45 degrees (not 135).

Comment: May the limp queen choose at each step whether it's clockwise or anticlockwise? Is Qa1-b1-c2-c3-b4-b5 a legal move?

Comment: Of course the queen gets to decide what way to turn, else it can only make one path (an $8$-loop).

Comment: I think you should clarify that it's $\pm$45 degrees. In math, positive degrees denote anti-clockwise rotation.

Answer (score 9):

To kick this thing off, I've got:

> 32 (50%) moves on an 8x8, but *68* (68%) moves on the 10x10 and a very nice 108 (75%) on the 12x12 illustrating a parity-swap mechanism:
>  [image]

EDIT: I've come across useful patterns that provide good answers for even $n$ greater than 6:

> [image]
>  The 4k+2 case is fairly straightforward: the dense section connects the outer strands to the inner strands, and the looser bottom connects the outer strands to each other (and likewise the inner strands).
>  The 4k case looks more complicated, but it reduces to choosing an appropriate k-by-k system of loops, and finding a corresponding k-by-(k-1) to fill in the middle. If you've chosen your pair wisely, you can take a pair of loops and twist them together, merging the two loops into a single path as shown here: [image]

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlU2P.png)

Comment: You can shift the central portion of the 8x8 path two steps to the right...

Comment: @DanielMathias Yes, but how could that shifted part connect with the rest while maintaining the 45 degree turn rule? Edit: Wait, I think you're right and it is possible if you cross the two ends over.

Comment: Also note that the question didn't specify that $n$ must be even; for odd numbers the gap is a bit different.

Comment: I noticed that, and investigated odd grids for a bit after posting the edit, but didn't see any meaningful way to improve upon the shown patterns.

Answer (score 5):

The fruits of my labor:

> Pears, I guess?
>  [image]
>  10 x 10 - 24 = 76
> 12 x 12 - 24 = 120

Extension to larger grids:

> For all even $n>10$, path length $n^2-2n$
>  [image]

Improvement, possibly optimal:

> For all even $n>8$, path length $n^2-24$
>  Shown above: $n=10$ and $n=12$
>  Shown here: $n=14$ and $n=16$
>  [image]
>  Possibly optimal: $n^2-20$ would be optimal (minimum: 5 unvisited cells near each corner), but I have been unable to find such a path.

Comment: Can you prove $n^2-2n$ is optimal?

Comment: @littlecat I can prove that it isn't.